# All other links redirect except downloader

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-connect, downloader

I have a private client testing server set up and for some reason all the links work except for magento connect. For example.

http://myserver.com/clientname/ (is the root for the Magento installation)

When I click on Magento Connect from the admin panel it redirects to this site
http://myserver.com/clientnamedownloader

Now every other module/page seems to work and nothing seems abnormal in my .htaccess file and the correct permissions are setup for the folders.

Comment: In `System > Config > Web` are you sure you have the trailing slash on the link URLs? Check your `RewriteBase` setting in your `.htaccess` too

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment check what you have under `System->Config->Web` as the downloader link is built from `Mage::getBaseUrl('web')`

If you are still having these issues this can be debugged by looking into the controller `Mage_Connect_Adminhtml_Extension_LocalController`

```
/**
 * Redirect to Magento Connect
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('web') . 'downloader/?return=' . urlencode(Mage::getUrl('adminhtml'));
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issues occurred because you don't' have downloader folder in root path. if you have downloader folder on root path then delete connect.cfg files and try again.